# Tabs widget does not display correctly

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I understand that this is all PRE-ALPHA code so I may not get an answer.

I am working on this project:  https://github.com/dannymk/AdminInterface

I can't get the tabs to display at all.  As a matter of fact the tabs-widget template seems to be rendered "raw" when I inspect the elements on the page.

The tabs work when I use static values, however that is not really useful.

Where am I going wrong?

Widgets:  http://dart-lang.github.io/widget.dart/

```dart
    <!-- wgp-contentpanel.html -->
<link rel="import" href="packages/widget/components/modal.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/widget/components/tabs.html">
<polymer-element name="wgp-contentpanel" attributes="contentpanelactive title">
   <template>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/AdminInterface/web/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <modal-widget id="modal_content_panel">
          <div class="modal-header">
             <button on-click="{{ closeContentPanel }}" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
             <p>{{ title }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
             <tabs-widget>
                <template repeat="{{ tab in tabs }}>">
                   <li class="{{ tab.active }}">
                      <a href="#{{ tab.id }}" data-toggle="tab">{{ tab.title }}</a>
                   </li>
                </template>
                <template repeat="{{ tab in tabs }}>">
                   <p id="{{ tab.id }}">{{ tab.content }}</p>
                </template>
             </tabs-widget>
          </div>
      </modal-widget>
   </template>
   <script type="application/dart" src="wgp-contentpanel.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

.

```dart
// wgp-contentpanel.dart 
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('wgp-contentpanel')
class WGPContentPanel extends PolymerElement{
   bool get applyAuthorStyles => true;  
   bool get resetStyleInheritance => true; 
   @published String title = "";
   @published bool contentpanelactive = false;

   @observable List tabs = toObservable([{ "active" : true,
                                   "id" : "one",
                                "title" : "First",
                              "content" : "First tab content"
                             },
                             { "active" : false,
                                   "id" : "two",
                                "title" : "Second",
                              "content" : "Second tab contents"
                             }]);

   WGPContentPanel.created() : super.created();

   contentpanelactiveChanged(){
      if ( this.contentpanelactive ){
         var modal = $['modal_content_panel'];
         modal.show();

      }

   }

   closeContentPanel(){
      this.contentpanelactive = false;

   }

}
```

If I replace the tab-widget template like so it works great:

```dart
          <tabs-widget>
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">First</a></li>
            <p id="tab1">First tab contents</p>
            <!-- template repeat="{{ tab in tabs }}>">
               <li class="{{ tab.active }}">
                  <a href="#{{ tab.id }}" data-toggle="tab">{{ tab.title }}</a>
               </li>
            </template>
            <template repeat="{{ tab in tabs }}>">
               <p id="{{ tab.id }}">{{ tab.content }}</p>
            </template -->
         </tabs-widget>
```

Comment: You posted the HTML twice and Dart code not at all.

Comment: What do you mean by this: ` the tabs-widget template seems to be rendered "raw"` and by this `when I use static values`.
If you see the `#document-fragment` node as first subnode of your custom element then it is loaded as custom element.
I checked out your project. The main problem I have is that several stylesheet links point to non-existing files. But when you run the app in DartEditor the output window should show these errors.

Comment: Sorry, I did not include the bootstrap assets into the project.  I don't think I should see:  <tabs-widget>
   <template repeat="{{ tab in tabs }}">
      #document-fragment
   </template>
      ...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is easy:
The 0.3.0-dev version from GitHub is under development. The author is working on support of Polymer.dart, so some features won't work until he fixes them.

For sure, try to visit the project [website](http://dart-lang.github.io/widget.dart/#tabswidget), where tabs don't work also.

If you want to use tabs from widget.dart, I recommend using older 0.2.7 version from pub.dartlang.org, which works perfectly, but which is based on the deprecated Web UI.

There's been an Issue already on the author's GitHub [repository](https://github.com/dart-lang/widget.dart/issues/12). You can probably add Pull request, if you want to contribute.

Comment: OK, as I said I know all this stuff is under development and may have bugs.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using the correct Dart syntax to reference a map element.
I was using "object.key" instead of "object['key']", lesson learned: when jumping between Perl, Java, Javascript and Dart, make sure you verify your syntax before reporting bugs :-)